# Probability over 0 with mixed effects hurdle model intepretation

Tags: probability, mixed-model, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

I am presenting a publication from Functional Ecology for a journal club. I am having extreme difficulty interpreting the results from a mixed effects hurdle model they present. How can the probability be reported as over 1? I am clearly misinterpreting how it is presented but have no idea what else it could mean. I am specifically referring to the value under "probability of oocyte (or spermary) production" in the "response of nonbleached colonies at mean colony size". I am happy to attach the paper for further digging if it helps: Johnston et al 2020 "The legacy of stress: coral bleaching impacts reproduction years later".[image: Table from paper]

Comment: Perhaps they have misinterpreted log odds (or something akin to that, depending on the model) as "probability," because you're right: it's ridiculous to characterize negative numbers or numbers above 1 as probabilities! However, that might not be what the table is trying to say: doesn't its caption clarify that these are "probability ... per polyp per colony"?  Moreover, it looks like they might be reporting *estimated coefficients* in the model, not actual probabilities per whatever.  It would be very helpful to state what the model is so your readers can understand this table.

Comment: @whuber I think you may be on to something about the coefficients- they don't have any distinction of what this is for abundance either, BUT the values do match for diameter differences which they state they measure in micrometers.